# postgres sql : getting unified rows

Tags: postgresql

I have one table where I dump all records from different sources (x, y, z) like below

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | source |
+----+--------+
| 1  |  x     |
| 2  |  y     |
| 3  |  x     |
| 4  |  x     |
| 5  |  y     |
| 6  |  z     |
| 7  |  z     |
| 8  |  x     |
| 9  |  z     |
| 10 |  z     |
+----+--------+
```

Then I have one mapping table where I map values between sources based on my usecase like below

```
+----+-----------+
| id | mapped_id |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | 2         |
| 1  | 9         |
| 3  | 7         |
| 4  | 10        |
| 5  | 1        |
+----+-----------+
```

I want merged results where I can see only unique results like

```
+-----+------------+
| id  | mapped_ids |
+-----+------------+    
| 1   | 2,9,5      |
| 3   | 7          |
| 4   | 10         |
| 6   | null       |
| 8   | null       |
+-----+------------+
```

I am trying different options but could not figure this out, is there way I can write joins to do this. I have to use the mapping table where associations are stored and identify unique records along with records which are not mapped anywhere.

Comment: the logic is when 1 is mapped to 2 and 9, it is assumed that they three are equal similarly 3 and 7 are equal. whereas 5,6,8 are not to mapped to any records and they are unique on their own. Hence I want to get the output as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is, you want to see all dump_table IDs that do not appear in the mapping_id column and then aggregate the mapped_ids for those that are left:

```
select d1.id, 
       array_agg(m1.mapped_id order by m1.mapped_id) filter (where m1.mapped_id is not null) as mapped_ids
from dump_table d1
  left join mapping_table m1 using (id)
where not exists (select *
                  from mapping_table m2 
                  where m2.mapped_id = d1.id)
group by d1.id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/JQZ17650

Comment: thanks for quick response. as I said, I can not use name for grouping purpose, it was just for understanding, I have different conditions to map these rows in dumped table. Can we do this just by using dump_table id and then association table id,mapped_id?

Comment: @Learner: if you want to include the `name` in the output you have to "group" it somehow. Especially as you want to combine the same names with different IDs to a single one, e.g. `abc`

Comment: it solved the problem, just wanted to check if there would be any performance issues if I have huge number of records Eg. 100k to 1 million

Comment: I tried this and updated the query again, looks like above solution is not handling one of the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, ARRAY_AGG(mapped_id) AS mapped_ids
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 USING (id)
GROUP BY id, name
```

Comment: thanks. as I mentioned I can not use name, I updated the above query by removing name from select and group by clause but it gives all records from table1.